# Set different datacontext in one view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have 2 Windows. From the first window I'm calling second :

```
var window = new WindowButtonClick("Graphic") {DataContext = new GraphicViewModel()};
window.ShowDialog();
```

Here is XAML of second window:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowButtonClick"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:graphic="clr-namespace:Windows.Graphic"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
<Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type graphic:GraphicViewModel}">
        <graphic:Graphic />
      </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
```

and constructor:

```
public WindowButtonClicks(string title)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Title = Application.Current.Resources[title].ToString();
}
```

So how can I set DataContext, that it will **show title that I pass in constructor as window Title and ContentControl will show one of the viewModels(GraphicViewModel in this case)** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem in WPF. Luckily, it has a simple solution. You'll need to use a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So you'll need to set the `DataContext` to one object, whose properties you can data bind simply to like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PropertyOfDataContext}" />
```

And for any properties that are declared in the `Window` or `UserControl`, you can use the `RelativeSource Binding` like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PropertyOfWindow, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={
    x:Type YourXamlPrefix:YourWindow}}}" />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You said:

> I will have 20 ViewModels, that I want to load to ContentControl

If you had only provided *all of the relevant information* when asking your question, then you would have had a better answer by now. This is a different problem, but can be fixed just as easily. In this case, you can just set your view models to their views using `DataTemplate`s... just define one for each view model/view pair like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel1}">
    <Views:View1 />
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModelN}">
    <Views:ViewN />
</DataTemplate>
```

Note that I did *not* set the `x:Key` values... this means that the specified views will be implicitly rendered by the Framework whenever it comes across objects of the relevant type. Then to display the `View1` from this example, you'd just need to do this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{PropertyOfTypeViewModel1}" />
```

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

Wow... I really hope that you've explained your problem properly this time because this is my last update. So I can't really see a problem with what you are asking for... you want to set a property in the constructor to be displayed as the `Window.Title`. This would definitely work:

```
public WindowButtonClicks(string title)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Title = "Some Title";
}
```

So if your code doesn't work, then you must have a problem with your call to `Application.Current.Resources[title]`... have you actually checked whether that returns a value or not? If it does, then you have a real problem, because it is perfectly acceptable to set the `Window.Title` like this.

If `Application.Current` is returning `null`, then just make sure that you set it to an instance of `MainWindow.xaml.cs` in the code behind:

```
// In MainWindow.xaml.cs constructor
Application.Current = this;
```

Other than that, your problem is impossible to determine from the information that you have provided.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I will have 20 ViewModels, that I want to load to ContentControl... In this case I cannot write x:Type myXamlPrefix:MyWindow

Comment: I appreciate your help and probably I didn't provide relevant information again. All that you describe is right, but this part is working. The Problem is that I cannot set Title of the created window. If you will have a look at constructor (WindowButtonClicks) I set to a Title string variable, but I cann't see it on my created window. That's the problem

Comment: Thanks for the last update. Unfortunately I have a real problem, because resource is returned and set to title. In debug I can see, that the title is updated, but it is not updating it on the window...

Comment: @Sasha, if you have another question, then please ask a new question, rather than extending this one. On Stack Overflow, we like each post to contain a single programming problem as this makes it easier to find what you want in searches.

Comment: it's the same question. Title is set to a value from resource, for example "Some Title", but when window is loaded, there are no Title.

Comment: Apologies for my misunderstanding. If a property change won't update in the UI, then it usually means one thing... you haven't implemented property change notification. You either need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, or declare your `Title` property as a `DependencyProperty`.